# Change the location of /tmp in a Windows install of Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash, msys2

the `TMP`/`TEMP` directory in Windows 10 usually points to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp`. When using Git bash, the `/tmp` directory "magically" refers to that location, too.

How can I change this behavior upon startup of the Git bash such that `TMP`, `TEMP` (for Windows programs started by Git bash) and the `/tmp` location refer to a different directory, e.g. `C:/myTemp`?

(Changing `TMP` or `TEMP` globally in Windows is not a viable option for me...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/fstab`, comment out any existing lines defining `/tmp`, and add this one:

```
C:/myTemp /tmp ntfs auto
```

The `ntfs` part doesn't matter because the system figures out the filesystem on its own.  The `auto` part tells the system to mount it automatically when you start your shell.  There are other options you might want to specify, like case sensitivity.  For more information about that file, see:

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

After editing that file, you'll need to open a new shell.